# Running JAX-RS 2.0 / Jersey on Grizzly 2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, grizzly

I want to run JAX-RS 2.0 / Jersey on Grizzly 2, but I don't now how to set it up. I found the following Maven dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
  <artifactId>grizzly-framework</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-m09</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-m05-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-m05-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-m05-1</version>
</dependency>
```

What Java Code do I need to run Jersey on Grizzly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows how you can create a skeleton of your project from a maven archetype (it has some basic code): http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/snapshot/getting-started.html#new-from-archetype

You can also browse through Jersey 2 samples here: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples

Most of them are grizzly-based.

Comment: what example did you chose?